# Servlet Script in Eclipse

Tags: java, servlets, parameters, show

My Servlet name is ShowParameters and My Html is ShowParametersPostForm.html. I included the package coreservlets for Show Parameters. How to link the HTML with the servlets. When i run it says that the requested resource is unavailable.

How to link my servlet in following code?

```
<FORM ACTION="coreservlets.ShowParameters" METHOD="POST">
Item Number: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="itemNum"><BR>
Description: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="description"><BR>
Price Each: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="price" VALUE="$"><BR>
<HR>First Name: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="firstName"><BR>
Last Name: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="lastName"><BR>
Middle Initial: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="initial"><BR><HR>
</FORM>
```

Comment: Please include `servlet` and `html` code in your post.

Comment: Can you add some relevant code here?

Comment: Can you please elaborate, what are you trying to achieve and share some code snippets if possible?

Comment: If you're new to Servlets, then you should read [our Servlets wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to map your request to Servlet in `<servlet-mapping>` tag of `web.xml`
Have a look at this [tutorial](http://javapapers.com/servlet/what-is-servlet-mapping/) and you'll find what you need

```
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>coreservlets.ShowParameters</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/show</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

and have your action as `<form action="show">`

Comment: because when you provide action in your form that request needs to go somewhere so by providing mapping you make sure that the form request comes to you servlet and hence you can process your form data in your servlet

Comment: can you post your web.xml file

Comment: The requested resource (/ShowParameters/coreservlets.ShowParameters) is not available. I am having this same problem for all my servlets.. That what i asked how to servlets in HTML..

Comment: have you changed your form's action attribute can u post it in your question not in comment

Comment: change `<FORM ACTION="coreservlets.ShowParameters" METHOD="POST">` to `<FORM ACTION="show" METHOD="POST">` and it will work